# connection with couchdb server interrupted while uploading a file

Tags: couchdb

What happenes if the connection is interrupted during a document upload? The document isn't saved to server? or it is saved partially? The document contain an image/jpeg attachment in base64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial writes are not allowed, so you'd need to re-write it.